# Why doesn't Ubuntu need to download package that you have previously had installed on your system

Tags: apt

When I install, for example, *Chromium*, for the first time, it takes a while and is clearly getting the files from the web servers. Then, I remove it, it assures me that it was removed. Then, when I install it again, it does not download any files and installs in less than a second. So, by my logic, programs are not truly getting deleted? Perhaps the file system keeps them on until the hard drive space is actually needed, like the recycle bin function? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It uninstalls the program, yes. You will be unable to execute it.

It just keeps the "installers" (`deb` files) in the `/var/cache/apt/archives` directory.

But if you have a `deb` of an older version, and a newer version of the package has been released, APT (Ubuntu's package manager, stands for Advanced Packaging Tool) will download the newer version.

You can clean them by running `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get autoclean`.